# How do I download all files I have in Wolfram Cloud to my desktop?

Tags: wolfram-cloud

I have recently been saving my files to Wolfram Cloud for convenience as I am using different computers for work.

I would like to routinely back up the files to my local desktop.

If I were to do this I would need to click each file in the cloud one by one and manually click  download.

Is there a way I can write a notebook to do this automatically as I have 100+ files and I would like to do this job quite regularly?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use [`CloudObjects`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CloudObjects) and [`CloudDirectory`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CloudDirectory) to find your files:

```
objects = CloudObjects @ CloudDirectory[]
```

> ```
> {CloudObject["https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/carlw/Base"], CloudObject[
> "https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/carlw/Copied Files"], CloudObject[
> "https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/carlw/Marathon"], CloudObject[
> "https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/carlw/Resources"], CloudObject[
> "https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/carlw/marathon"], CloudObject[
> "https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/carlw/trash"]}
> ```

Here is the first cloud object in the "Copied Files" directory:

```
obj = First @ CloudObjects[objects[[2]]]
```

> ```
> CloudObject["https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/carlw/Copied Files/01-starting-out-elementary-arithmetic-exercises.nb"]
> ```

Once you find the right directory, you can copy them with [`CopyFile`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CopyFile):

```
CopyFile[obj, FileNameTake @ Information[obj]["Path"]]
```

> ```
> "/Users/carlw/Desktop/01-starting-out-elementary-arithmetic-exercises.nb"
> ```

Comment: This looks like it will work. Thanks !

Answer (score 5):

This is the code I ended up using. It also looks into directories 1 level and copies those files too.

```
localBackupPath = "C:\\Users\\";
objects = CloudObjects@CloudDirectory[];
type = Information[#, "FileType"] & /@ objects;
allObjects = 
  Flatten[MapThread[
    If[#2 === Directory, CloudObjects[#1], #1] &, {objects, type}]];

CopyFile[#, 
   FileNameJoin[{localBackupPath, 
     Information[#, "DisplayName"]}]] & /@ allObjects
```