# How to download all from wolfram cloud while preserving folder tree structure?

Tags: wolfram-cloud

This answer: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/201726/62529 allows downloads of all files from wolfram cloud. However, it does not preserve the folder tree.

I have a lot of files I want to download and they have folders nested within folders.
These folders make it painful to have to reorganize all my files after downloading.

How can I download everything and not loose my folder organization?

I tried modifying the code (I linked to earlier) by changing `Information[#, "DisplayName"]` to `Information[#, "Path"]`, but this gave me errors

```
localBackupPath = "C:\\Users\\username\\Desktop\\WolframBackup";
objects = CloudObjects@CloudDirectory[]
type = Information[#, "FileType"] & /@ objects;
allObjects =
    Flatten[MapThread[
        If[#2 === Directory, 
            CloudObjects[#1], #1] &,
            {objects, type}]];
CopyFile[#,
    FileNameJoin[{localBackupPath,
        Information[#, "Path"]}]] & /@ allObjects
```

Comment: Probably because the destination directories do not exist so `CopyFile` fails.

Comment: Am I to understand that in order to import your cloud scripts to run on your desktop, you need to write a program to do the import?  That this isn't supported directly by either wolfram cloud or Mathematica?

Comment: That's correct. Wolfram cloud has a button to download them one by one, but not everything at once.